# Is the title input box's placeholder text "What's your Islam question?" grammatically correct?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

The placeholder text of the site's question title input box reads

> What's your Islam question? Be specific.

it seems grammatically incorrect. Right?

Shouldn't its be something like

> What's your Islamic question? Be specific.

or

> What's your Islam related question? Be specific.

?

Comment: [Is “What's your Islam question?” grammatically correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/141563/54608)

Comment: Well, [at least we have capital letters now](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/624/214).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not knowledgeable enough to say whether or not it is gramatically correct or not, but I can say it looks weird.  I also agree that it would be better if it is:

> What's your *Islam-related* question? Be specific.

Comment: I'd go with *Islam-related*. Compound adjectives should be hyphenated.

Comment: I've asked for this to be updated...Done.  ;-)

Comment: @JonEricson Hope [christianity.se] and others follow suite.